# Are Django Q objects (complex queries) secure?

Tags: python, sql, django, security, django-q

I can't seem to find any resources explaining the security of Django's built in complex queries (Q objects, or F objects). Is it possible to inject a SQL attack in these queries? I did a small test:

```
from models import *
from django.db.models import Q
q = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(mycolumn__contains='%; DROP DATABASE mydatabase;'))
print q
>>> []
print q.query
>>> SELECT `mydatabase_mytable`.`mycolumn` FROM `mydatabase_mytable` WHERE 
    `mydatabase_mytable`.`mycolumn` LIKE BINARY %\%; DROP DATABASE mydatabase;%
```

This doesn't seem to have dropped my database though. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from your SQL, Django is escaping the LIKE clause. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements) is a reference to what is happening in that case.

In general, Django does protect you from SQL injection attacks. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) is their security page. Note that you can get in trouble by executing custom SQL or by using "extra" carelessly, but otherwise, you are protected.

Comment: Using `extra()`, or using underlying connection/cursor with raw SQL directly.